# Fixed button stops working after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made div "button" which has fixed style so it would always stay at one place even when scrolling page. Here is the code

```js
var backButton = document.getElementsByClassName("go-back");
for(i = 0; i < backButton.length; i++) {
 backButton[i].style.cursor = "pointer";
 backButton[i].onclick = function() {
     hideIstorija();
     hideVerta();
     hideSarasas();
     showStarting();
    }
}
```

```css
.go-back {
 position: fixed;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 bottom: 0%;
 margin: 50px;
 padding: 25px;
 border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="go-back">
    <
</div>
```

When the page is fully scrolled up, it works as intended, but after scrolling a bit down button stops working. Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: There might be multiple cases depending on other content. It's possible the button is actually obscured by some transparent element on top of it. Does the cursor change while you hover it? Maybe try adding to your css `z-index:100` (or some other arbitrarily big number)?

Comment: This indeed helped my case! Thank you!

Comment: @MichałSadowski You can post answer I will mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here might be multiple cases depending on other content. It's possible the button is actually obscured by some transparent element on top of it, especially if the cursor doesn't change while hovering over it. Adding `z-index: 100` (or some other arbitrarily big number) can help.